# Serve files embedded in .net library to HTML in Blazor

Tags: javascript, c#, embedded-resource, .net-standard, blazor

I am creating a [Blazor](https://blazor.net/) project v0.5.1 that is using a .NET Standard library to provided all of the business logic.  This library has several WAV files stored as Embedded Resources.

Consuming one of the resources in a typical .NET technology (WinForms, WPF, etc.) that reference this library can be done with this:

```
var assemName = "MyLibName";
var assembly = AppDomain
    .CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .First(a => a.GetName().Name == assemName);

//memory stream
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assemName}.mysound.wav");

//Can play the file at some point later
var player = new SoundPlayer(stream)
player.Play();
```

I would like to do the equivalent in Blazor.  Right now, I have sounds working in the app by copy/pasting the wav files into `wwwroot\sounds` folder of the project so it is served as static HTML content.  Then, in JavaScript, I can play one like this:

```
const audio = new Audio"\sounds\mysound.wave"]);
audio.currentTime = 0;
audio.play();
```

But what I would really like to do is avoid the copy-paste and somehow serve out the files dynamically as those endpoints so it is transparent to JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to get it.  Not sure it if the the best way but it seems to work well.

I had to add the blazor Storage extension:

https://github.com/BlazorExtensions/Storage

which acts as a proxy to the JavaScript SessionStorage and LocalStorage from .NET.  Once loaded, I added each embedded wav file  from .NET like this:

```
foreach (var kvp in SoundStreamDictionary)
{
    await sessionStorage.SetItem(
        kvp.Key.ToString().ToLower()  //Key is the name of the sound
        , kvp.Value.ToBase64()  //Value is a Stream object
    );
}
```

The `ToBase64` is pretty standard .NET stream manipulation:

```
    public static string ToBase64(this Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Position = 0;
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
```

Now all data is stored in JavaScript SessionStorage as strings.  Trick is now to decode that to audio.  With the help of this JS helper method (thanks to this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40831598/1324284)):

```
function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

    const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    const byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }

    return new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
}
```

Put that and this in the JsInterop.js file of the BlazorComponent:

```
const soundAudios = [];

window.JsSound = {

    loadSounds: function (sounds) {
        sounds.forEach(sound => {
            //Blazor.Storage extension adds extra double quotes so trim
            const str64 = sessionStorage.getItem(sound.path).slice(1, -1);

            const blob = b64toBlob(str64, "audio/wav");
            const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            const audio = new Audio(blobUrl);
            soundAudios[sound.id] = audio;
        });

        return true;
    },

    play: function (id) {
        const audio = soundAudios[id];
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();

        return true;
    },
};
```

And FINALLY the sounds can be invoked by name from .Net:

```
private IDictionary<string, int> soundDict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

public Task<string> LoadSounds(IEnumerable<string> fileNames)
{
    var sounds = fileNames
        .Select(name =>
        {
            var snd = new
            {
                id = soundDict.Count,
                path = name
            };
            soundDict.Add(name, snd.id);

            return snd;
        })
        .ToList();

    return JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<string>(
        "JsSound.loadSounds"
        , sounds
    );
}

public Task<string> Play(string name)
{
    return JSRuntime.Current.InvokeAsync<string>(
        "JsSound.play"
        , soundDict[name]
    );
}
```

Comment: That means, if you have, say, list of files of 5mb each, and you want them to be embedded, you going to keep it in a session storage?

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, that is exactly what is happening.  The files in my case were very small, say, < 50KB each.  Not sure how it would perform w/ 5MB.  Might be ok.